# Automation deployment software

Tags: deployment, automation

Tell me please is there some gui software to the deployment of applications and databases under windows platform?
I need to configure, install, update and uninstall an applications from the changing list on several servers from one place ( by the mouse click is pefrect )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Kwatee](http://Www.kwatee.net). It runs under tomcat/mysql on Windows, Linux or Mac. It has a web gui for configuration and deployment management but you can also automate with CLI scripts.